# Creating Child Record of Parent Class

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Having a bit of trouble understanding how to attach my foreign key to my child record when I insert it into my db. I have a casino class that can have many different locations within the casino(Restroom, Restaurant, Valet, Etc.). I am trying to create a new record in my db of the location and include the foreign key(casino_Id) which is the id of the casino table. I am not sure how I would be able to obtain that id unless I pass it in directly from the post by the route which I am doing in my show.blade.php file within my casino views.

```
<a href="/casino/{{ $casino->id }}/location/create"><button class="btn btn-primary">Add Location</button></a>
```

Not entirely sure if this is a practical/safe way of passing in that info or how to obtain it from my create function. Currently I have it finding the first casino record it can find in the db to see how it inserts it which it does insert into the db but does not include the foreign key on insert.

web.php

```
//Location Routes
Route::get('/casino/{casino}/location/create', 'LocationController@create');
Route::post('/location', 'LocationController@store');
Route::get('/location/{location}', 'LocationController@show');
Route::get('/location/{location}/edit', 'LocationController@edit');
Route::patch('/location/{location}', 'LocationController@update');
```

casino.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Casino extends Model
{

    public function locations() {
        return $this->hasMany(Location::class)->orderBy('title', 'ASC');
    }

}
```

location.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Location extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['title'];

    public function casino() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Casino::class);
    }

    public function duties() {
        return $this->hasMany(Duty::class)->orderBy('title', 'ASC');
    }

}
```

create and store functions in my LocationController.php

```
    public function create() {
        return view('locations.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $casino = Casino::find(1);

        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',

        ]);

        $casino->location = new location([
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
        ]);

        $casino->location->save();
        return redirect("/casino/1");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your route from

```
Route::get('/casino/{casino}/location/create', 'LocationController@create');
Route::post('/location', 'LocationController@store');
```

to

```
Route::get('/casinos/{casino}/locations/create', 'LocationController@create');
Route::post('casinos/{casino}/location', 'LocationController@store');
```

Your create action

```
public function create(Casino $casino) 
{
    return view('locations.create', compact('casino'));
}
```

Your store action

```
public store(Request $request, Casino $casino)
{
    $request->validate(['title' => 'required']);

    $casino->location()->create($request->validated());

    return redirect("/casino/{$casino->id}");
}
```

[Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

Comment: In your create method too, you need to pass, `$casino`, let me edit my answer.

Comment: How would I pass that to my store method. Since in my create.blade.php for locations it gives me an undefined variable for $casino when I use it for my form action. `<form action="/casino/{{ $casino->id }}/location" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">`. Should I try to grab it in the create method of the LocationController with the id I have in the url from the route then return it with the view in create?

Comment: Is this the most practical way of achieving this solution? It certainly works but want to make sure I'm not going about eloquent the wrong way.

Comment: @poomulus read route-model-binding concept, it is the correct way.